# Find List Of Dynamic stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to find list of stored procedures having dynamic queries in them.

Is there any way to that?

Comment: select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%exec%'

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start. You can execute a dynamic SQL using `EXEC` and `sp_executesql`, so you want to search for stored procedures containing those commands:

```
SELECT
    SP_NAME = o.name
FROM sys.sql_modules m
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
    m.definition LIKE '%EXEC%'
    OR m.definition LIKE '%SP_EXECUTESQL%'
```

---

As suggested by Coder of Code, instead of `sys.objects`, you could `JOIN` it to `sys.procedures`.

Here are other method's according to my google search:

Using `sys.procedures`:

```
SELECT
    SP_NAME = name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE  
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%EXEC%'
    OR OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)LIKE '%SP_EXECUTESQL%'
```

Using `sys.sql_modules`:

```
SELECT
    SP_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE
    OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID, 'IsProcedure') = 1
    AND (
        definition LIKE '%EXEC%'
        OR definition LIKE '%SP_EXECUTESQL%'
    )
```

Comment: you can inner join direactly on the `sys.procedures` to get only procedures.Or there any issue with that ?

Comment: You could do that too, it's even easier to remember. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @wewesthemenace Your code still not refering sys.procedures

Comment: I did not update the code, I just put a statement below indicating you could do it too.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help

```
select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%exec%' AND 'SOME OTHER CONDITIONS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select b.name as Sp_Names from sys.syscomments a,sys.procedures b 
where  a.id=b.object_id and (a.text like '%exec%' or a.text like '%sp_executesql%')
```